# to determine time within range of times in php for the 48 hrs clock

Tags: php, datetime

i want to check the time 4 pm to 4 am (nextday) . How it will achieve?

Code is :

```
<?php
$start = strtotime('2016-03-01 16:00:00'); // it is evening time

$end = strtotime('2016-03-02 04:00:00'); // it is morning time of next day


if(time() >= $start && time() <= $end)
{
    echo "okay";
}
else
{
    echo "not okay";
}
?>
```

It goes on else part everytime.

Comment: Since we are already past 2016-02-27 04:00:00, why would you expect it not to go to the else part?

Comment: its already past that time range, its march already

Comment: lets assume time and date for today and day after tommorrow .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to check the server timezone, it may be the problem for your wrong result. You can set the default time zone in your script also.
Please have a look on the below code, here i just put Dubai time zone as default and checked the code , it is working as expected , It may help you.

```
<?php
     date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Dubai');
     $start = strtotime('2016-03-01 08:00:00'); // it is evening time
     $end = strtotime('2016-03-02 04:00:00'); // it is morning time of next day
    if(time() >= $start && time() <= $end)
    {
        echo "okay";
    }
    else
    {
       echo "not okay";
    }
?>
```